# Example of a smoothing of a curve over a DVR

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a DVR, $C=X\cup Y\cup Z\subset \Xi$ be a singular curve, where each two components of $C$ intersect transversely in one point.

[image]

Could someone please help me to construct a example of a smoothing of $C$ over $Spec(R)$?

By a smoothing of $C$, I mean a flat morphism $\pi:\Xi\rightarrow Spec(R)$, where $\Xi$ is a regular surface, such that the fiber over the special fiber is $C$ and the generic fiber is smooth.

Comment: What is $\Xi$ in this question? You do not define it.

Comment: $\Xi$ is the surface, sorry for the mistake and thank you!